# How to save array of inputs to a child schema in a nested mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save a survey which contains multiples questions. Each time I enter a question and the answers and click the save button it should push it to the question array and at last when I click the save survey button the whole question should be saved under the parent schema 'survey'.

How can I do this with nodejs and mongoose? What I tried is here....

**Mongoose schema**

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    surveyname: String,
    question  : [{
        que: String,
        ans1: String,
        ans2: String,
        ans3: String,
        ans4: String

        }]
    });

 module.exports=mongoose.model('Survey',SurveySchema);
```

The js file where I save the inputs to the schema

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var survey = require('../models/QBank');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){ 
  new survey({
    surveyname: req.body.sname,
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
      question.question.push({
        que: req.body.que,
        ans1: req.body.ans1,
        ans2: req.body.ans2,
        ans3: req.body.ans3,
        ans4: req.body.ans4
      });
    }

    }).save(function(err, doc){
      if(err) res.json(err);
      else
          req.flash('success_msg', 'Question saved to QBank');  
      res.redirect("/CreateSurvey");

    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

I am stuck  here with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an atomic update method like **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** for your post where you can specify the `upsert` option. If `upsert` is true and no document matches the query criteria, **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** inserts a single document. Here that's where you can also use the native
**[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)** operator to push the new question and answers to the question array, rather than using a loop when you can let mongo do all the work on the server.

The following example shows how you can refactor your code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Survey = require('../models/QBank');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){ 
    Survey.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "surveyname": req.body.sname }, /* <query> */
        { /* <update> */
            "$push": {
                "question": {
                    "que": req.body.que,
                    "ans1": req.body.ans1,
                    "ans2": req.body.ans2,
                    "ans3": req.body.ans3,
                    "ans4": req.body.ans4
                }
            } 
        },
        { "upsert": true }, /* <options> */
        function(err, doc){ /* <callback> */
            if(err) res.json(err);
            else
                req.flash('success_msg', 'Question saved to QBank');  
            res.redirect("/CreateSurvey");
        }
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the above, the fields and values of both the `<query>` and `<update>` parameters are created if the `<update>` parameter contains update operator expressions. The update creates a base document from the equality clauses in the `<query>` parameter, and then applies the update expressions from the `<update>` parameter.

Comment: Excellent! I tried your answer and it works perfectly. It keeps on adding question inside a survey. How to terminate this and start  a new survey? I am a beginner, help me with this also please.

Comment: The above would be ideal for a `PUT` HTTP Verb i.e. updating an existing survey by adding questions to the array. However, you can use the [**`create()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) or [**`save()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) methods for a `POST`, there are some examples in the documentation on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var survey = require('../models/QBank');
var Survey = new survey();
var question = [];
question[0] =  req.body.que;
question[1] =req.body.ans1;

// do for all
Survey.question = question;
survey.save(Survey, function(err, doc){})
```

Comment: Inside a question there must be the answers.

Comment: I tried the above answer. But I am getting this error : TypeError: survey.save is not a function

Answer (score 0):

According to your description you may passed full question to save in DB.

Assumed you passed data in `req.body` with multiple question. 
like:

```
{surveyname: 'your survay name', question: [{que:'q1',ans1:'a1',....},{que:'q2'..},{que:'q3',..}]}
```

If assumption is correct then can use like:

```
router.post('/path', function(req, res, next){ 
  var newSurvay = new survey({
    surveyname: req.body.surveyname,
    question: req.body.question
    });

  newSurvay.save(function(err, doc){
      if(err) res.json(err);
      else
          req.flash('success_msg', 'Question saved to QBank');  
      res.redirect("/CreateSurvey");

    });
});
```

Comment: How can I pass multiple questions as you have stated above from the front end?

Comment: first of all push all question in an array then set in an object `var question = [{que:'q1',ans1:'a1',....},{que:'q2'..},{que:'q3',..}]; var data = {sname: 'your survay name', question: question};` and then send this **data** in *http* call `$http.post('/path', data)`

Comment: I do not know how to push all questions to an array. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you using **angular.js**  or what is your front end technologies to call API?

Comment: Yes I am using angular.  But till now I have used it only for partial templating

Comment: can you show your current process to call this API ?

Comment: See my HTML form and js file where I post to database in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318698/how-to-use-angular-to-collect-many-form-submits-and-submit-at-once-to-mongoose-m

Comment: Added answer for that question

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to populate your survey object when you enter question and answer and hit save button.Then you can use ajax form submit to send the data to the desired route.

Let's say the survey object is like the following

```
var randomSurvey = {
   surveyname: "randomSurvey",
   questions:[
             {     
                que: "question1",
                ans1: "answer1"
                ans2: "answer2"
                ans3: "answer3"
                ans4: "answer4"
              },
              {     
                que: "question1",
                ans1: "answer1"
                ans2: "answer2"
                ans3: "answer3"
                ans4: "answer4"
              }
            ]
}
```

And when you press the save survey button then your post route should be like this.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){ 

  //Grab your data here sent over ajax form submit 
  var randomSurvey = req.body.randomSurvey;

  var newSurvay = new survey(randomSurvey);

  newSurvay.save(function(err, doc){
      if(err) {
         //do something with err
      }
      else{
        // do something with the result;
      }             
      res.redirect("/your_redirect_url");    
  });
});
```