# How to use angular to collect many form submits and submit at once to mongoose model?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to save surveys that contain multiples questions. One survey has many questions. Likewise there must be many surveys. Each time I enter a question and the answers and click the *saveQuestion* button. I am using Angular and want to save that in an array (in front end). After I save all the questions of a survey and click the *saveSurvey* button, I want to save the survey to the mongoose schema.

Can I use two submit buttons for a form? If not what is the solution?
I had asked about this issue in my previous question.

[How to save array of inputs to a child schema in a nested mongoose schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278594/how-to-save-array-of-inputs-to-a-child-schema-in-a-nested-mongoose-schema)

**But I do not know how to Collect form submits in an array in front end and send to post route at once.**

I searched a lot and may be there is something to do with 'ng-repeat'.

> MyForm

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/CreateSurvey" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="que" placeholder="Click to enter question" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="ans1" placeholder="Click to enter answer" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="ans2" placeholder="Click to enter answer" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="ans3" placeholder="Click to enter answer" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save Question</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save Survey</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Mongoose Model

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    surveyname: String,

    question  : [{
        que: String,
        ans1: String,
        ans2: String,
        ans3: String,
        ans4: String

        }]
    });

 module.exports=mongoose.model('Survey',SurveySchema);
```

> How I post to the mongoose schema

```
 var express = require('express');   
 var router = express.Router();
 var Survey = require('../models/QBank');

 router.post('/', function(req, res, next){

 new Survey({
 surveyname: req.body.surveyname,
 question  : [{
  que: req.body.que,
  ans1:req.body.ans1,
  ans2: req.body.ans2,
  ans3: req.body.ans3,
  ans4:req.body.ans4

  }]

}).save(function(err, doc){
  if(err) res.json(err);
  else
  req.flash('success_msg', 'User registered to Database');  
  res.redirect("/CreateSurvey");

});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: you can also do it by replacing `Save Survey` with a radio button!

Answer (score 0):

do you have multiple form or no? if you have one form you can use input type button instead of type submit to save question in front end.. you can use ng-click on input type button and save it to an array in that controller.
if you're question is dynamic you can use type [Mixed] in you're model..

but in my idea you can send your data with jquery ajax and you don't need to use form element

Comment: I want the user to type and create questions and answers. That's why I use a form. Can I do that with jquery ajax? where can I find about that? Eg: tutorial

Comment: if you use angular you can use $http instead of jquery ajax to send you're data.. search about $http in angular.. its so ea

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The above answer by Roy explains that.

Answer (score 0):

You can push multiple question in an array and finally submit to api with multiple question.

in the same form add a button to push question in an array and another button to submit survey information to api.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="addSurvay()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="s" class="col-sm-2 control-label">S Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="s" ng-model="surveyname" placeholder="Survay name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="q" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" ng-model="questionObj.que" placeholder="Question">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="a1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a1" ng-model="questionObj.ans1" placeholder="Answer 1">
      </div>
    </div>
    // ans 2,3,4 div 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addQuestion()">Add question</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add survey</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Controller Code:

```
$scope.addQuestion = function() {
    $scope.question.push($scope.questionObj);
    $scope.questionObj ={};
  };

  $scope.addSurvey = function() {
    $scope.data ={surveyname:$scope.surveyname, question: $scope.question};
    $http.post('/path', $scope.data);
  };
```

For more details see [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/kbFMr8tEqN3FgdL2xJ4V?p=preview) and server part in [another question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278594/how-to-save-array-of-inputs-to-a-child-schema-in-a-nested-mongoose-schema/41280084?noredirect=1#answer-41280084)